# MVC Remote validation, parameter is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public LogOnModel LogOnModel { get; private set; }
        public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; private set; }
    }
```

in my RegisterModel I have email address like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        [Remote("IsEmailAddressAvailable", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

My validationController:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable(string emailAddress)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            
        }
}
```

The view @Model is UserProfile, the emailAddress in ValidationController is null.

I tried to change the ValidationController to look like this with no luck:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable([Bind(Include = "EmailAddress")]RegisterModel register)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: Pacman, could you please show use your View? cshtml?

Comment: Im kinda facing the same problem... have you solved this ?

Answer (score 12):

Your thinking about using *Bind* attribute is correct. Instead using *Include* parameter, you should use *Prefix* parameter. So your controller should look:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable([Bind(Prefix = "RegisterModel.EmailAddress")]string EmailAddress)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

So Prefix parameter binds parameter sent by browser with action parameter.

Comment: Is there a reason the Microsoft documentation wouldn't mention this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#remote-attribute 
I also noticed some other articles on this topic left out such an important detail.

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect this to be a model binding issue.  Try changing the action signature to something like this:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable([Bind(Prefix="RegisterModel")]string emailAddress)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Notice the `[Bind(Prefix="RegisterModel")]`, which was slightly similar to what you were trying to do from your latter attempt, so I think you were on the right track.  I basically pulled this from a very similar answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985495/437456), so maybe that trail can help you out further if this doesn't quite do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that comes to my mind is that as you are having another model (RegisterModel) as another model's property (UserModel), when you use the `Html` helper to render the model property like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.RegisterModel.EmailAddress)
```

it will render it something like

```
<input type="text" name="RegisterModel.EmailAddress"/>
```

MVC **model binding** works on the name properties and you are recieving `string emailAddress` in the first example and `RegisterModel model` in the second attempt, try using the `UserModel model` as the recieving parameter of the remote validtion ActionResult like

```
public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable(UserModel model)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either return true (validation passed), or a string of the error message in your validator. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

```
public class ValidationController : Controller {
    public JsonResult IsEmailAddressAvailable(string EmailAddress) {
        return Json("Email Address unavailable", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```